# Existing Angular Project into PWA

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

Which commands am I to run in my command line to modify my angular project into a pwa just like react-pwa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the angular suggested command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project <project-name>
```

This is the official guide: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started